# PHP - Access Class' Method from function

Tags: php, function, class, object, pdo

I want to access an Array from a PDO-Object using a function.
My code looks like this:

```
class ClassName {
       function __construct() {
             ...
       }
       function a() {
             ...
       }
}

$object = new ClassName();
function b() {
       $var = $object->a();
       return $var;
}
```

My problem is that function b won't execute function a. I already tested function a  without function b and everything works fine..

Is it possible to call function a within function b?

Comment: its out of scope

Comment: to use `$object` inside function `b()`, you could instantiate it inside the argument and pass it as argument, then you could use the objects methods inside that function

Answer (score 0):

This two functions must be in separate php file.
Let say function a is in file className.php
and function b inside file myFunction.php

So, inside myFunction.php
Move the class object inside function b

```
require 'ClassName.php';
function b() {
       $object = new ClassName();
       $var = $object->a();
       return $var;
}
```